# agregar autocomplete a inputs creados dinamicamete

Tags: javascript, html

Espero me puedan ayudar...
Tengo varios dias tratando de resolver este pequeño problema, sucede que tengo una tabla con una fila inicial y un boton que agrega mas filas (filas dinamicas)... La cuestión es que los inputs tienen la función autocomplete, de los cuales los valores para el autocomplete los mando a traer desde mi DB y sucede que el autocomplete solo funciona para la primera fila de la tabla y para las filas que se crean dinamicamente no funciona, les dejo el códio para ver si me puede ayudar.
De antemano gracias a todos...

```
<table width=100% cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tabla_materiales">

      <tr height="35">
      <td class="w3-panel w3-border w3-border-black">
      <center><label>Material o Refacción</label></center>
      </td>

      <td class="w3-panel w3-border-top w3-border-bottom w3-border-right  w3-border-black">
      <center><label>Cantidad</label></center>
      </td>

    <td class="w3-panel w3-border-top w3-border-bottom w3-border-right  w3-border-black">
      <center><label>Costo Unitario</label></center>
      </td>

          </tr>

          <tr height="30">
      <td width="488px" class="w3-panel w3-border-bottom w3-border-right w3-border-left w3-border-black"><center>
      <input type="text" name="txt_material_refaccion" id="txt_material_refaccion" class="txt_material_refaccion" value="" style="width:100%; text-align:center; autofocus" required></center>
      </td>

      <td class="w3-panel w3-border-bottom w3-border-right  w3-border-black"><center>
      <input type="text" name="txt_cantidad" id="txt_cantidad" class="txt_cantidad" value="" style="width:100px; text-align:center; autofocus" required onkeypress="return valida(event)"></center>
      </td>

    <td class="w3-panel w3-border-bottom w3-border-right  w3-border-black"><center>
      <input type="text" name="txt_costo_u" id="txt_costo_u" class="txt_costo_u" value="" style="width:100px; text-align:center; autofocus" required onkeypress="return valida(event)"></center>
      </td>

          </tr>
          </table>


<center><input type="button" class="btn" name="btn_agrega_fila2" id="btn_agrega_fila2" value="Agregar Fila" style="width: 110px; height: 28px"></center>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn_agrega_fila2').click(function(){
        agregar2();
    });

});

var count2 = 2;
function agregar2(){
val2 = count2;
var fila2='<tr height="30"><td width="350px" class="w3-panel w3-border-bottom w3-border-right w3-border-left w3-border-black"><center><input type="text" name="txt_material_refaccion'+ count2++ +'" id="txt_material_refaccion'+val2+'" class="txt_material_refaccion" value="" required></center></td><td class="w3-panel w3-border-bottom w3-border-right  w3-border-black"><center><input type="text" name="txt_cantidad'+val2+'" id="txt_cantidad'+val2+'" class="txt_cantidad" value="" required onkeypress="return valida(event)"></center></td><td class="w3-panel w3-border-bottom w3-border-right  w3-border-black"><center><input type="text" name="txt_costo_u'+val2+'" id="txt_costo_u'+val2+'" class="txt_costo_u" value=""  autofocus" required onkeypress="return valida(event)"></center></td></tr>';
    $('#tabla_materiales').append(fila2);
    reordenar();
}
</script>


<script>
var tags=<?php echo json_encode($array);?>;
$( "#txt_material_refaccion" ).autocomplete({source: function ( request, response ) {
var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );response( $.grep( tags, function ( item ){
return matcher.test( item );}) );}});
</script>
```

Comment: estás añadiendo el `autocomplete` al elemento con id `"txt_material_refaccion"` y el atributo id es algo que deberia ser único. ergo solo lo aplica al primero. Si lo aplicas a una clase, se lo añade a todos pero no a las nuevas filas que añadas. tendrás que añadir fila y añadirle el autocomplete cuando la agregues.

Comment: @lois6b algunas suerencias para hacer lo que me comentas???
La verdad es que desconozco sobre el tema

Comment: tienes `$( "#txt_material_refaccion" ).autocomplete` para añadir el autocomplete al elemento con id `txt ...` .. te sugiero cambiarlo por un selector que use clase, nombre, o un atributo personalizado ya que el id es unico. y el codigo que usas para crear el autocomplete, usarlo cada vez que añades una fila tal que `fila2.autocomplete ....`

Comment: el detalle es que en esa fila teno mas inputs, por eso solo quiero que se aplique a ese input, igual ese input pertenece a una clase en css misma que agrego en html `class="txt_material_refaccion"` existe alua forma de que el _autocomplete_ se lo pueda agregar a dicha clase???

Comment: si lo quieres asignar al que tenga esa clases, por que no usas un selector de clases? algo como `$( ".txt_material_refaccion" ).autocomplete...`

Comment: @FranIslas lo intentaré...